# AC not working, open wire. How to find/fix it?

Tags: electrical, hvac, roof

This is for S. California. My friend packaged unit (AC + heater) on top of her condo didn't start (the Air Conditioner) this week. The unit is old and the heater part of it was disabled a couple of years ago. The whole unit is very old (from 1988). The AC still run last summer but now it is dead.

**The problem:** The unit runs on 240VAC. The white and black wire from the breaker (double pole 40A, inside the condo) measure 240VAC. The wires at the "Box" (see picture) measured about 150VAC. At the "Box", the white wire to ground shows 120VAC. The black wire to ground shows about 30VAC. I removed the black wire from the terminal inside the "Box" and re-measure to ground ... I got about 60VAC. There seem to be an open in the black wire. I tried to poke the black wire (there is a break in the conduit) before it enters the roof down to the condo but still got like 30VAC (just like at the "Box" after reconnecting it to its terminal).

I'm wondering if the break could be in the section of the wire in the roof between the flexible rubber cup and the break in the conduit (between the two arrows that show "Goo?" in the picture). The problem is that if I find it there how to fix it? If not, how do I "goo" the (new?) conduit back in place? BTW the "rubber cup" is part of the roof that is under HOA control and I don't want to mess with it. Thanks.

[image: Roof with AC]

[image: close up]

UPDATE: Here is a picture of the breaker box.
[image: Breaker Box]

Comment: I would get the HOA/condo to look at it.  You do something and the roof leaks, guess who will get the bill.  That break might already be letting water in.  Wire breaks are hard to find, but If the conduit goes all the way, it is simple to pull new wire and probably faster than looking for the break.

Comment: The conduit ends at the top of the rubber cup. The wires look like individual wires but the one coming out of the breaker box is a Romex type cable. The cable is stapled to some stud(s) and to the roof it goes. Overall the cable from the breaker box to the roof is only like 4-6 feet long. I learned a long time ago, when I was a board member for 10 years, not to get the HOA involved in stuff like this unless I want them to do the work which is still an option.

Answer (score 6):

If your HOA is like ones that I'm used to seeing, you can't do this work yourself. It will need a licensed electrician. The electrician will be able to cut the existing conduit and install a new piece from the roof to the disconnect, then run new wire if needed. Whoever put the 'goo' on there likely already broke the conduit and didn't want to bring in an electrician to fix their mistake, so they just put some roof material over it to stop the leak. It's a lazy, lazy fix.

On the (unlikely!) chance that the HOA actually allows DIY electrical work, the steps are the same. Pull a permit. Shut off the power. Get some new conduit that is compatible with what comes out of the roof. Detach the wires from the disconnect. Cut the roof conduit. Unthread it from the wires and remove all the old conduit. Check the wires for damage. If they are damaged, you will need to plan for a new pull, hopefully using the old wires as pull string. Glue on new conduit and an appropriate fitting, threading the wires through as you go. Complete the conduit run to the box, again threading wires through as you go. Reconnect the wires. Check to see if everything works. If it doesn't, find the break in the wires now that you've fixed the conduit. Fix or replace the wire. Call in the inspector to get you work signed off.

Or something like that. I might be missing a small step or two because the pictures don't show everything, but that's the general shape of things. If anyone sees anything I missed feel free to edit it in or comment.

Comment: The HOA is not permitted to allow DIY work.  A multi-unit condo building will require a licensed electrician because of state or local rules protecting innocent owners from incompetent work.  That's not an issue on an owner-occupied single family home.

Comment: That's what I figured, just not definitively enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Make the conduit corrections I described below, add a junction box where you transition from indoor cable to outdoor conduit with THWN wires in it.

Run whatever cable your new heat pump will require - this should be stated on the equipment nameplate, take the running amps and multiply by 125% then choose appropriate cable for that.

---

The goo was put there by the roofer to attempt to seal the coupler there where the RMC conduit meets the liquidtight FMC conduit (rigid meets flexible). It can go away, not your problem.

The FMC conduit is completely degraded and beyond repair, and will need to be replaced entirely.  That is incredibly dangerous as it is, as it's a matter of time before weather action rubs a hot wire against the FMC shell and creates a huge short.  It may have already done that and burned out a splice somewhere.

I see individual wires in that conduit, meaning the conduit is being used *as proper conduit* and not as a sleeve for cable.  Fortunately, the conduit rules require that all wires be "pullable" with gentle curves or access points in all the right places, and all those access points must remain accessible forever. They can be behind a bookshelf, but not behind a *built-in* bookshelf.  **So once the conduit is repaired, it should be a simple matter to pull the old wire and replace it** - it's not designed for exposure to direct sun.  Also note white is not a legal wire color for hot. I don't see a reason for neutral to be there.

As for the heat pump (or air conditioner with an electric toaster heater) - **Replace that with a modern wide-range heat pump that does not require toaster heat**.  You will save a ton of money because it'll be more efficient, but also, there are rebates from the utility company or government.

Comment: I added a comment in the previous answer where I point out that the cable coming out of the breaker box is a Romex type cable and not individual wires. Your answer seems to indicate that individual wires are required to be inside the conduit so maybe the sleeve was removed up in the roof to comply with that but it is Romex and it is certainly not "pullable" or "accessible forever". Maybe the regulation from 1988 was different.

Comment: @Rodo It wasn't. That means there should be a junction box before the start of that conduit, where the Romex is spliced to THHN wires for traveling through the conduit.  Romex is not allowed outdoors, and conduit outdoors is outdoors.  Also, water deteriorates it - a Romex line will start tripping GFCIs if it gets wet.  If they brought stripped Romex wires up that conduit, that work was "amateur hour" - not a licensed electrician, probably an HVAC guy.  Fix it properly. Find an interior location for a junction box to tie in. The licensed electrician will take care of that.

Comment: They can replace the breaker with a BQC or BRD *provided* they replace the 15A half-width breakers on either side of it at the same time

Comment: What's a BQC or BRD?

Comment: @Rodo it is a type of circuit breaker.  E.g. if you needed a 30A for the heat pump, Eaton BRD2302115 or BQC2302115.  Or even a BQ2302115 since you don't actually need common trip.   If you need a different ampacity just change "30" to whatever in the part numbers.